# Count columns which are not letter or blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I want to count the days in a month whose day or night data is not equal to 0 or letters.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday | Monday | Tuesday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Thursday |
| 2 | Day | Night | Day | Night | Day | Night | Day | Night |
| 3 | n/a | 10 | n/a | 0 | 5 | 5 | 10 | blanc |

In 3rd row, if in a day, daytime or nighttime is not a letter or 0, than that day counts 1.
So, the result of the above example should be 3. (monday + wednesday + thursday)

This is the long form of the formula.

```
=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(A3)=TRUE;A3>0);AND(ISNUMBER(B3)=TRUE;B3>0));1;0)+
IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(C3)=TRUE;C3>0);AND(ISNUMBER(D3)=TRUE;D3>0));1;0)+
IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(E3)=TRUE;E3>0);AND(ISNUMBER(F3)=TRUE;F3>0));1;0)+
IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(G3)=TRUE;G3>0);AND(ISNUMBER(H3)=TRUE;H3>0));1;0)
```

I could solve with countif or sumproduct if there weren't two conditions for a day, but I couldn't count with two conditionals.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are those `n/a` manually typed or formula returned and the word blanc is actually excel `""`?

Comment: They are formula which returned as " " but also there are formulas returned as letters (A,B,Z etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I3</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:H1,(A3:H3<>"")*(A3:H3<>0)*(NOT(ISTEXT(A3:H3)))),1)<>""))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I3</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:H1,ISNUMBER(A3:H3)*(A3:H3>0)),1)<>""))
```

---

None of the solutions returns error, if there is no non zero number:

[image]

---

Update:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I3</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((ISNUMBER(A3:H3)*(A3:H3>0))/
  COUNTIFS(A3:H3,">0",$A$1:$H$1,$A$1:$H$1),0))
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I am using Office Professional Plus 2019 and I don't have Unique formula.

Comment: @Seigneur formula updated use the one with `SUMPRODUCT()` function and let me know: `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((ISNUMBER(A3:H3)*(A3:H3>0))/
  COUNTIFS(A3:H3,">0",$A$1:$H$1,$A$1:$H$1),0))`

Comment: This works as array formula (ctrl + shift + enter). Thank you, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your task interactively or automated.

Interactively enter formulas into cells as depicted below then select A7:B7 and fill it right till the end of your table.

```
A6=N(A3)+N(B3)
I6=COUNTIF(A6:H6;">0")
```

Regardless of how many rows and columns the table has, this solution can be implemented in 4 steps only (Q3 is based on the depicted data sample):

1. Enter the first formula into J3.
2. Fill right J3:K3 up to Q3.
3. Enter to I3 this formula '=COUNTIF(J3:Q3;">0")'.
4. Fill down I3:Q3 up to the last row.

Then J:Q can be hidden.

Use the appropriate cell instead of Q3 based on the number of columns in the input table.

**Or** create and use the VBA function as sampled in I3.

```
Function CountNumDays(ir As Range) As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, d1 As Double, d2 As Double
  k = ir.Columns.Count
  If k Mod 2 = 0 And ir.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To k Step 2
      d1 = 0
      d2 = 0
      On Error Resume Next
      d1 = CDbl(ir.Cells(i))
      d2 = CDbl(ir.Cells(i + 1))
      On Error Resume Next
      If d1 + d2 > 0 Then j = j + 1
    Next
    CountNumDays = j
  Else
    CountNumDays = CVErr(xlErrNA)
  End If
End Function
```

There is no special action required to use user-defined functions. They act as the embedded Excel functions. **Since CountNumDays is incorporated into the workbook, nobody needs to interact with VBA.**

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. I can't enter formulas below because there are a lot of rows in the table, not just one as in the example.
Also I don't prefer use macro because it is a shared document and not everybody knows how to use macro.

Comment: There is no special action required to use user-defined functions. They act as the embedded Excel functions. Since CountNumDays is incorporated into the workbook, nobody needs to interact with VBA.